# Cross Platform AES 256 GCM Javascript & Elixir

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptography, erlang, elixir

I have been trying to encrypt in Javascript and decrypt in Elixir using AES 256 with GCM. I borrowed some examples from here and there and came up with the following.

Encryption in Javascript

```
const _crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(message, secret) {
  // random initialization vector
  const iv = _crypto.randomBytes(16);

  // extract the auth tag
  const cipher = _crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', secret, iv);

  // encrypt the given text
  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(message, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

  // extract the auth tag
  const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

  const encrypted_message = Buffer.concat([iv, tag, encrypted]).toString('base64');
  return encrypted_message;
}

const secret = _crypto.randomBytes(32);
encrypt("secret message", secret);
```

Decryption in Elixir

```
def decrypt(encrypted_message, secret) do
  secret_key = :base64.decode(secret)
  ciphertext = :base64.decode(encrypted_message)

  <<iv::binary-16, tag::binary-16, ciphertext::binary>> = ciphertext
  :crypto.block_decrypt(:aes_gcm, secret_key, iv, {"AES256GCM", ciphertext, tag})
end

# secret would be the secret from javascript encoded in base64
decrypt(encrypted_message, secret)
```

And my result on Elixir side has always been `:error`
I have feeling is that it has something to do with encoding and decoding, but I can't seem to find out where and what went wrong.

If someone can point me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATED Working Version**

for those who intend on using the same languages:

Javascript Encryption

```
const _crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(message, secret) {
  // random initialization vector
  const iv = _crypto.randomBytes(16);

  // extract the auth tag
  const cipher = _crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', secret, iv);

  // add the following line if you want to include "AES256GCM" on the elixir side
  // cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from("AES256GCM", 'utf8'));

  // encrypt the given text
  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(message, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

  // extract the auth tag
  const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

  const encrypted_message = Buffer.concat([iv, tag, encrypted]).toString('base64');
  return encrypted_message;
}

const secret = _crypto.randomBytes(32);
encrypt("secret message", secret);
```

Elixir Decryption

```
def decrypt(encrypted_message, secret) do
  secret_key = :base64.decode(secret)
  ciphertext = :base64.decode(encrypted_message)

  <<iv::binary-16, tag::binary-16, ciphertext::binary>> = ciphertext

  // make sure _AAD is an empty string "" if you didn't set it during encryption
  :crypto.block_decrypt(:aes_gcm, secret_key, iv, {_AAD, ciphertext, tag})

  // otherwise, you would need to set _AAD to whatever you set during encryption, using "AES256GCM" as example
  // Note: AAD (Associated Authenticated Data) can be whatever string you want to my knowledge, just to make sure you have the same in both encryption and decryption process
  // :crypto.block_decrypt(:aes_gcm, secret_key, iv, {"AES256GCM", ciphertext, tag})
end

# secret would be the secret from javascript encoded in base64
decrypt(encrypted_message, secret)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: your `"AES256GCM"` should not be present (or null, I'm not that familiar with Erlang). It represents the additional authenticated data and is included in the calculation of the authentication tag, obviously making it different from the authentication tag generated by the encryption code.

`:aes_gcm` already specifies the mode, and the key size is of course determined by the size of `secret_key`, so the string would be quite unnecessary anyway.

Comment: It works! when I set "AES256GCM" to "", and it successfully decoded. I have thought it was there to correspond with `aes-256-gcm` on the javascript side. Thanks so much!!